# CocoaPods: RealmSwift will only install version 1.1.0

Tags: swift, realm, cocoapods

I have an old XCode project that I'm trying to update to XCode 9.0 and Swift 4.0 and no matter what I do, I can't manage to get Realm to install the latest version using CocoaPods.

Here's the Podfile:

```
target 'MyTarget' do

use_frameworks!

pod 'RealmSwift'

end
```

which results in the output:

```
Using Realm (1.1.0)
Using RealmSwift (1.1.0)
```

My other projects use 2.10.0 for what seems like an identical configuration. Any ideas on how to force Cocoapods to install the latest version of RealmSwift?

Comment: Cocoapods will try to install the dependencies at the specified versions listed the Podfile.lock file. To update the dependencies to the latest versions just do a `pod update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to run "pod update".